# how to access data stored register in elmeasure device, in raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I connected `elmeasure device` in `raspberry pi`, `elmeasure device` display's the `voltage`, `current` and `wattage`. these `voltage`, `current`, `wattage` values stored in respective `register address` in `elmeasure device`.

Is it possible to retrieve register data using `python programming language`....?

how to access elmeasure register data in raspberry pi...?

please help me with this it's very important....